# display only datas that contain images from a list of item

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

here iam having a list of items which contain both images and non images and i want to display the items which have images..
here is my view page

```
 <?php foreach($clients as $row){?>
 <?php $images=json_decode($row->image);{?>
 <?php if($images){;?>
    <div class="client"> <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/<?php echo $images[0];?>" alt="" class="grayscale wow bounceIn"  data-wow-delay=".1s"> </div>

 <?php }}}?>
```

here is my controler..

```
public function index($p_id=null)
{
    $data['active_mn']='index';
    $data['clients']=$this->Nowaste_model->get_clients($p_id=4,6,0);
    $this->load->view('index',$data);
}
```

here is my model

```
public function get_clients($p_id,$limit,$offset)
  {

  $this->db->select('client.*','category.id');
  $this->db->join('category','category.id=client.category_id');
  $this->db->order_by('client.id','desc');
  $this->db->where('category.id',$p_id);
  $query = $this->db->get('client',$limit,$offset);
  return $query->result();
}
```

here is my table name client

```
id  image                        category_id
1   ["upld-file1460797715.jpg"]     6
2   ["upld-file1460797733.jpg"]     6
3   ["upld-file1460797831.jpg"]     6
4   ["upld-file1460797847.jpg"]     6
5   ["upld-file1460797864.jpg"]     6
6   ["upld-file1460797882.jpg"]     6
7     null                          6
8     null                          6
9     null                          6
10    null                          6
```

my joining table name category looks like this

```
id  category_name   parent_id
    6   builders        4
    4   client          0
    7   hospitals       4
    8   municipalties   4
```

the problem facing here is all the datas are displaying here which i dont need i need only which had images to be diplayed.if limit is removed iam getting all images but i want to use limit also

Comment: Use `echo $this->db->last_query();` to print your query . check your query directly into phpmyadmin for errors

Comment: Check what is in your `$p_id` you're passing to `get_clients()`

Comment: Mark correct answer if you got it @MAHAMMED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in model

```
public function get_clients($p_id,$limit,$offset)
{

   $this->db->select('client.*','category.id');
   $this->db->join('category','category.id=client.category_id');
   $this->db->order_by('client.id','desc');
   $this->db->where('category.id',$p_id);
   $this->db->where('client.image !=', 'NULL');
   $query = $this->db->get('client',$limit,$offset);
   return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: the syntax used in the where condition is wrong...by changing it like this i got it. $this->db->where('client.image !=', 'NULL');

Answer (score 0):

Change your get client function to something like this:

```
$query = new Query;
$query  ->select(['SELECT COLUMNS']) 
        ->from('TABLE_NAME_1')
        ->join(  'JOIN_TYPE',
                'TABLE_NAME_2',
                'TABLE_NAME_2.COLUMN =TABLE_NAME_1.COLUMN'
            );
$command = $query->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
return $data;
```

Comment: no..its its in the same mode.i guess problem is with my model

Comment: You need to put  `print_r($clients);` above the foreach loop.Also, please do let me know what results are you getting with your code?

Comment: array().iam getting like this

Comment: Then, you are not getting any data in $clients. It means there is something wrong with your query.

Answer (score 0):

i had changed my model like this and i got it

```
 public function get_clients($p_id,$limit,$offset)
  {
   $this->db->select('client.*','category.id');
   $this->db->join('category','category.id=client.category_id');
   $this->db->order_by('client.id','desc');
   $this->db->where('client.image !=', 'NULL');
   $query = $this->db->get('client',$limit,$offset);
   return $query->result();
  }
```